How does this set equality follow?
This is proposition 4.9 in Lee's intro to topological manifolds.

What I don't understand is the proof of part b where it is said that
$$ X = \overline{A} \subseteq{\overline{U}} = U $$
In particular, I cannot understand why $\overline{U} = U$
For the other parts of that equation, I believe the following reasons for why it is true.
I understand that $  X = \overline{A} $ as $A$ is assumed to be dense in X.
I \emph{think} but am not sure that  $\overline{A} \subseteq{\overline{U}} $ is true because:

$A$ is a connected set contained in $X = U \cup V$ hence by part a.) of the proposition we know $A$ is contained in either $U$ or $V$.

Now suppose WLOG that $A \subseteq U$:
Then let $p \in \overline{A}$ and $N$ be a neighborhood of $p$.
As $p \in \overline{A}$, we know that every neighborhood of $p$ must contain a point of $A$, but this point is also a point of $U$ as we know that $A \subseteq U$.
Hence $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{U}$
But I cannot figure out the last equality where
$$ \overline{U} = U $$
I know this is equivalent to saying that $U$ is closed in $X$, but I cannot think of why this is true since we assumed $U$ to be non-empty and open as $U$ and $V$ disconnect $X$.
Any help is appreciated thanks!

$V$ is open, so $U = X\setminus V$ is closed.

Yup thanks I get it now!

In the future, please, avoid the use of images, instead type your questions using MathJax

If I'm not mistaken, proving that $U$ is closed in X is quite streight forward. Since $U\cup V=X$, and $U\cap V =∅$, then $X/U=V$. So $U$ being closed is equivalent to $V$ being open, which is assumed since we said $U,V$ disconnect $X$.

Assume $X = U \cup V $ and $U$ and $V$ are disjoint and open. Then $U$ have to closed, because $$U = X\backslash V.$$ Thus $X$ ist connected iff $X$ and $\emptyset$ are the only open and at the same time closed subsets of $X$.
